# cpanel says httpd failed and through ssh it says running but its not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server, cpanel, httpd.conf

So under cpanel server information it says httpd (2.4.27 (cPanel))  failed and when I check httpd status on ssh it says running. I restarting multiple times via whm and ssh and all successful. However htaccess does not kick in site is offline. I have tried clearing iptables and it does nothing when I try to stop iptables altogether it says unit not loaded. 
 Rebooted server several times with no luck. Any advice will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: so cpanel says httpd is not running but when you `service httpd status` it says it is?

Comment: correct and htaccess doesn't kick in

Comment: what can it be? any suggestions?

Comment: now cpanel says httpd is online to but not working. I have put deny from all in htaccess and now when I remove it the cpu spikes to above 100 out of 6 cpus. no idea what it can be.

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade your cPanel version as latest is 2.4.28. Also Restart HTTP Server (Apache) from Restart Services, I hope, these actions will resolve your issue.